# Droparea dont function, Jquery -> Drag and drop show image and not upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, liquid

i have a small problem - i can add a file on click. only the dropzone dont work.
If I drag and drop the file in the browser, will be displayed and not uploaded.

```
    $('#trigger-attachment').click(function(event) {
      if ($('#attachment-1').val() == '') {
        console.log('trigger 1')
        $('#attachment-1').click();
        $('.not-needed-if-pdf-provided').remove();
      } else if ($('#attachment-2').val() == '') {
        console.log('trigger 2')
        $('#attachment-2').click();
        $('.not-needed-if-pdf-provided').remove();
        console.log('trigger 2')
      } else if ($('#attachment-3').val() == '') {
        console.log('trigger 3')
        $('#attachment-3').click();
        $('.not-needed-if-pdf-provided').remove();
      } else {
        alert('Maximal 3 Dokumente auswählbar. Entfernen Sie zunächst eines um ein anderes auszuwählen. Tipp: Fügen Sie mehrere Dateien zu einem PDF zusammen.');
      }
    });
    $('#trigger-attachment').on('dragenter', function() { if ($('input.attachment.active').length > 0) $(this).addClass('dragging'); });
    $('#trigger-attachment').on('drop', function() { $(this).removeClass('dragging'); });
    $('#trigger-attachment').on('dragleave', function() { $(this).removeClass('dragging'); });
    $('#trigger-attachment').on('dragexit', function() { $(this).removeClass('dragging'); });
    $('#trigger-attachment').on('dragend', function() { $(this).removeClass('dragging'); });
    $('input.attachment').click(function(event) {
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      console.log('click ' + $(this).attr('id'));
    });
    $('input.attachment').change(function() {
      console.log('change');
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      var number = $(this).data('no');
      var displayElement =  $('#display-attachment-' + number);
      if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        displayElement.empty();
      } else {
        var file = this.files[0];
        displayElement.html('<div onclick="$(\'#attachment-'+number+'\').val(\'\').addClass(\'active\');$(\'#display-attachment-'+number+'\').empty();">&times; '+file.name+'</div>');
      }
    });
```

#################### Here is the HTML INPUT ->

```
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">
        <div id="trigger-attachment" class="text-center">
          <img src="https://d17blcsvifkhsu.cloudfront.net/sites/5b056e1c85cde904fb840d8f/theme/images/share.svg?1540384342" style="max-width:40px;">
            <p class="green-label">
              (optional)<br>
            </p>
            <input class="attachment active" id="attachment-3" name="content[attachment_3]" data-no="3" type="file">
            <input class="attachment active" id="attachment-2" name="content[attachment_2]" data-no="2" type="file">
            <input class="attachment active" id="attachment-1" name="content[attachment_1]" data-no="1" type="file">
        </div>
        <div id="display-attachments">
            <div id="display-attachment-1" class="display-attachment"></div>
            <div id="display-attachment-2" class="display-attachment"></div>
            <div id="display-attachment-3" class="display-attachment"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

##### this class should just hide another one

```
    <div class="row pb-3 not-needed-if-pdf-provided">
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow it is good that you've added your code to show your problem but limit your code to only minimal verifiable example in which case you should include necessary CSS code also.